# Where To Start With Chrome OS Development

Tags: google-chrome-os

I was seeing about the release of Google Chrome OS, then I have some questions:

- Where I can start to develop for it?

  - In which languages?
- Which platform is good to develop?

  - Is possible to develop inside Chrome OS?

    - In which languages?
- Is there any repository to share and download Chrome applications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where I can start to develop for it?

Chrome OS is a bucket for the chrome browser. Just build a webapp and it will work

> In which languages?

HTML5, CSS3, Javascript

> Which platform is good to develop?

Webapps are entirely interpreted

Comment: Some server-side code can be compiled like an ASP.Net web application project, for example.

Comment: Sure, but that's not compiling for Chrome OS.

Comment: why is this a correct answer??, Chrome OS is different from the Chrome browser! no?

Comment: @ra170: Developing an application for chromeos is the exact same thing as developing an application for the chrome browser. You use html, css, javascript, and local storage, and call out to the server when you need data.

Comment: and there is no development without 'testing' :) so if you don't have the hardware (=Chromebook) - you can still test your code in Virtualbox... here is a short tutorial I did: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/chromeos-in-virtualbox-test-drive-it/

Answer (score 14):

A good start would to be understand what Chrome OS is.

Comment: Harsh, but awesomely so.

Comment: Better left as a comment on the question. -1

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to develop inside Chrome OS?

You may be interested in the [Bespin project](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Bespin) from Mozilla Labs. They aim to provide an IDE (written within a HTML5 Canvas object) to edit websites on the fly, and in the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to learn how to write extensions for Chrome.

At this moment, they are not available at the current release, but they WILL be on the next one and you may bet they'll be available in some way on Chrome OS.